# onBlur in innerHtml blocks the function

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions, one that is creating dynamicly a table with input fields, which dimensions are based on a variable k, inserted by the user, and another one that reads the values inserted again by the user in every field of the table and inserts them in a 2 dimensional array that I can call later. 
The problem is that the create table function does not work with onBlur inserted in it's code. 
The code is as follows:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var k;


            function genArray () {
                var A = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                        A[i] = [];
                        for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                            var id = "A" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                            A[i][j] = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
if (isNaN (A[i][j])) { 
                            alert ('Valoarea 'A[i][j]' nu este un numar. Reintroduceti valoarea');
}
                        }
                    }                       
            }

            function readGrad() {               
                k = parseInt(document.getElementById("grad").value);            
                if (isNaN(k)) {
                    alert('Gradul introdus nu este intreg, reintroduceti gradul matricii');
                }
                if (k == 0) {
                    alert ('Determinantul trebuie sa fie mai mare ca 1');
                }
                if (k == 1) {
                    alert ('Determinantul trebuie sa fie mai mare ca 1');
                }
                return k;
            }       

            function genTable(i,j) {            
                //var i,j = parseInt(document.getElementById("grad").value);
                var myTable = '<TABLE BORDER="1" BORDERCOLOR="BLACK">\n <TBODY>\n';
                for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    myTable += '  <TR>\n';
                    for (j = 0; j < k+1; j++) {
                        myTable += '    <TD>'+j+'</TD>\n';
                    }
                    myTable += '  </TR>\n';
                }
                for (i = 1; i < k+1; i++) {
                    myTable += '  <TR>\n';
                    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                        myTable += '    <TD>'+i+'</TD>\n';
                    }
                    for (j = 1; j < k+1; j++) {
                    myTable += '    <TD><input class="element" id="A' + i + j + '" onblur="genArray()"></TD>\n';
                    } 
                    myTable += '  </TR>\n';
                }
                myTable += ' </TBODY>\n</TABLE>\n';
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = myTable;
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #777; color: ddd;">
    <div style="margin: 20px;">
        <h1>Program de calculare determinant matrice de orice grad.</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        Introduceti gradul matricei
        <input id="grad" type="text" value="" style="width: 50px;" onChange="readGrad()">           
        <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="button" name="Calculate determinant" value="Generati tabel" onClick="genTable()"> 
    </div>
    <form name="Det Matrice">
        <div style="margin-top: 100px; float: left; width: 100%;">
            Introduceti valorile: 
            <table style="text-align: center;">
                <div id="container"></div>
            </table>
            <br>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like MIB2, because I can't see `k`.

Comment: jslint validates the code, k is defined by the user and read by another function. the table is generated if I delete the onBlur="genArray()"

Comment: you have a syntax error in one of your alerts: `'Valoarea 'A[i][j]'...` should be `'Valoarea ' + A[i][j]' +...`

Comment: i have set up a fiddle for you and others to test on at http://jsfiddle.net/HKeXh/

Comment: @jbabey: your fiddle doesn't works.

Comment: @dragon66 the fiddle is viktor's code, which doesn't work, which is probably why he is asking his question ;)

Comment: i have missed the syntax. i have corrected it and works just fine now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correct the syntax error of the alert, genTable() works. But you have logic problem in your code. You add onblur event handler to every text field in the generated table cell. So every cell input will trigger a call to the onblur event handler which will iterate the whole table. I don't think this is what you want. Besides, during the iteration, your parseFloat function will fail on all the empty cells. You should only trigger one call to genArray() perhaps by using a button.

Comment: yes you are right, however I would like to do that without a button. The idea is to check every field immediately after a value is inserted. The best solution I think is to initialize all fields with value 0.

Comment: @viktor: in that case, you need only check the just-inserted field and update the array instead of checking the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Try `onblur="genArray()"` instead of `onBlur="genArray()"`

Notice that it is all in lower case letters!

Comment: What does not work? Why cant you be more specific? Do you think we are freaking psychics?

Comment: per your request I have added the html code. When clicking on "Generati tabel" it does not happen anything.

Comment: @viktor: The function "genArray()" is called in your code. It works for me! Put an alert in your genArray() to see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Just correct the syntactical error in line 15 like described by jbabey in the comments.